# jsView: How to get current element during "onBeforeChangeEvent"

Tags: jsviews

I am wondering if there is a way that I can get the current element that is triggering the onBeforeChangeEvent function in jsViews. I want to get the current element that it is working on, to do some extra jQuery work on it.

A basic example is below:

```
  $.views.helpers({
    onAfterChange: function (ev)
    {

        //want to get element instance right here as an example.....
        if (!PageSettings.cancelUpsert && ev.type == "change")
        {
             //do somthing to element that is currently being processed.
        }
    }
  });
```

I searched through the objects being returned, but could find a stable way to get to the element.  Any ideas, or tips towards where to look would greatly be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a data-linked element, such as an input: `<input data-link="..." />`, whose change event triggered the change, you can get that from either `this.linkCtx.elem` or `ev.target`.

More generally, the `this` pointer is the `view` object that is being changed.

There are a number of helper methods on the view object that you can use to access different elements within that view. For example `this.contents("someSelector")` will return a jQuery object that selects top-level elements in that view, and `this.contents(true, "someSelector")` will apply the selector to filter on all elements in the view (deep search not just top-level).

(You can use the selector `"*"` to get all elements)

Comment: Why did I miss that one..  lol  Thank you so much. You have been awesome through out the life of views and helping everyone.  Thanks for the great library!